# Extremely Slow File Copy/Transfer Speed

Tags: kubuntu, kde, usb-drive, copy

I am on Ubuntu with KDE Plasma 5 and I am having a serious issue in which when I am copying files to a flash drive or memory card, copy speeds are extremely slow like around 2MB/s to 3MB/s which does not occur with my external hard drive which gives more than 17 MB/s.

I know that is not much of a comparison but compared to previous experiences, this take extensive amounts of time to copy files. Is this an existing issue with Ubuntu or KDE Plasma? If so what are possible solutions?

Comment: Just to help you narrow it down. Does this also occur when you copy via terminal?

Comment: Yea, just as slow.

Comment: Find interesting info: Start with card unplugged, in a terminal window, `journalctl --follow` and let it run, to follow the log messages, then plug in your card, copy files, remove card, analyze log messages.

Comment: Noticed something similar in Kubuntu 16.04. But not again since Ubuntu 17.04.